# Reading tsv file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have alot of tsv files that I would like to read them 1 by 1 and write the last coloum into other file.

Here is my Code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(path+'/'+filename,'r',encoding="utf8") as tsvin, open('temptweets.csv','a',encoding='utf-8') as csvout:
        tsvin = csv.reader(tsvin, delimiter='\t')
        csvout = csv.writer(csvout)
        count = 0
        for row in tsvin:
            try:
                count = str(row[-1])
            except ValueError:
                pass  # w.e.
            if len(count) >= 0:
               csvout.writerow([count])
```

Most of it, work perfect. But the Problem is that some of lines interpeted togther.
i.e. row varible getting more few lines contected togther, so it ends up that not only the last coloum is written into the file, but also **ALL** the coloums of the next line. It is stopping after few rows - can't tell why either.

I have tried to read the files in few other method (such as pandas) but got the same result.
I have also tried to open the input file and view all chars (notepad++) but all the lines (including the problmatic ones) **DO HAVE** CR:LF.
I **know** there is something wrong with the input file (the input file is given), but I would like to know if there is any way to solve it.

Comment: Can you identify the lines that are causing issues? It sounds to me like you have a delimiter escaping problem.

Comment: Try adding something like `if len(row) > 2:` below the `for` statement. That way it will skip rows which are empty perhaps have one entry. One entry might imply it is using a different delimiter.

Comment: @farlee2121 Yes, after looking in-deapth on the data I can see it is have to do with a link at the end of the line. And it stops when there is " at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your file might have multiline fields embedded in double quotes (but it's hard to tell without looking at the data).

Try to add `newline=''` in your `open()` call (and maybe add `quotechar='"'` to `reader()`, but that's probably the default).

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly

---

Or it could be the opposite, and maybe you need to turn off quoting to parse those files correctly..

Comment: Thank you. setting quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE does fix my problem!